# Only One Dataset Load After Deployment In SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I am using 2 data sets in my SSRS Report.One is for Chart And Another is for table. But after deployment i can see only one result at a time. Which means Once Table load the chart is not Loading or If chart Load the Table Data is not Loading. Please suggest the good solution.Thanks.Please Refer the below 2 figures.
[1.Only chart Loading Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFiew.png)

[2.Only Table Loading Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/433YP.png)

## DataSet For Loading Table

```
SELECT distinct STDEV(ORDER_RESULT) AS [Standard Deviation],
(select top 1 MIN from SIVA_ControlLimit  
where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE) 
order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'LSL',
(select top 1 MAX from SIVA_ControlLimit 
where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE) 
order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'USL',(AVG(ORDER_RESULT)-STDEV(ORDER_RESULT)*3) AS LCL,
AVG(ORDER_RESULT) AS Mean,(AVG(ORDER_RESULT)+STDEV(ORDER_RESULT)*3) AS UCL,
Min(ORDER_RESULT) AS MinOrderResult ,Max(ORDER_RESULT) AS MaxOrderResult 
FROM SIVA_ControlLimit where
VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE)
```

## DataSet For Loading Graph

```
SELECT distinct ORDER_RESULT,BATCH_NO,STDEV(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () AS [Standard Deviation],(select top 1 MIN from SIVA_ControlLimit  where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and 
TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE)  
order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'LSL',(select top 1 MAX from SIVA_ControlLimit 
where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE) order by BATCH_NO,STANDARDVALUE) 'USL',
(AVG(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () - STDEV(ORDER_RESULT) OVER ()*3) AS LCL,
AVG(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () AS [CL(AVG)],(AVG(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () + STDEV(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () *3) AS UCL,
Min(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () AS MinOrderResult ,Max(ORDER_RESULT) OVER () AS MaxOrderResult,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BATCH_NO,ORDER_RESULT) AS Row  
FROM SIVA_ControlLimit where VALIDATE_DATE in (@yr) and ITEM_CODE in (@ITEM_CODE) and  TEST_TYPE in (@TEST_TYPE) and BATCH_NO in (@BATCH_NO) and TEST_CASE in (@TEST_CASE) order by BATCH_NO`
```

Comment: As you have mentioned, it is happening after deployment. How about before deployment or in local?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your datasets are fighting for resources.

When you deploy a report, the datasets can run concurrently (at the same time). The first one to run is preventing the second from returning data. In Visual Studio, the datasets are run one at a time so you wouldn't see the issue (makes debugging more interesting).

Since it looks like you are using the same database for both datasets, you can try checking the **Use Single Transaction** box to force them to run one after the other.

[image]

The downside of this approach is that any **#TEMP** tables won't be automatically removed between datasets but that doesn't seem to be an issue in your queries.